# The 25th works for Geo and me or Geo and I

Tags: grammar

Which is correct? "The 25th works for Geo and Me or the 25th works for Geo and I."

Answer (score 0):

"Me" is correct, since it is a 2nd-person object pronoun used as the object of the preposition "for". As a sound check, remove Geo and compare "The 25th works for me." with "The 25th works for I." The first version is correct.

Comment: Sadly, more and more native English speakers don’t have an instinctive understanding that constructs like ‘‘for I’’ are wrong.

Comment: Hello, mickery. It's highly likely that basic questions like this will be closed as duplicates, unsuitable for a site aimed at linguists, deficient in research ... Supplying an 'answer' just encourages more unsuitable questions.